# How to run select query of post with category and tags?

Tags: posts, categories, query, sql

I want to fetch multiple posts with categories and tags 
currently I'm using this query:

```
$pagesize = 20;
$pageNumber = 1;

$mysql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT p.post_title,
     p.ID,
     p.post_content,
     p.post_date,
     p.post_name as url,
     t.name as category_name
FROM wp_posts p,
     wp_terms t,
     wp_term_relationships r,
     wp_term_taxonomy tt
WHERE p.post_status='publish' AND
     tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND
     p.id=r.object_id AND
     r.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id AND
     tt.term_id = t.term_id
ORDER BY p.post_date desc 
LIMIT ".(int)($pageNumber*$pageSize).",".(int)$pageSize."") or die ("error".mysqli_error($con));
```

The mysqli-connection works. But when I run this code, I only get a blank page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Blank page in WordPress means, there is a fatal PHP error in your code. Also the `or die()` statement could cause the white page. You should not use `or die()` in production code, instead use `try .. catch`

2) Besides this I strongly discourage you from using mysqli_* functions in WordPress. Always use [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for DB access!

3) Your query has some issues, but those will not cause the blank page but possibly incorrect results.

4) In this case you possibly want to use core WP functions instead. Like [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) and [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)

Answer (score 0):

Turn on [`debug`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) (to true) it will allow you to see error.